# ImpressPages 4_0_16, 404 errors for all other pages then index.php

Tags: http-status-code-404, impresspages

i moved my installation from a local place to a new host. the index.php works but other links dont. researched errors for older impresspages versions tell to modify the ip_config.php and change the base url. in the new version there is not such file and the base url gets updated over the admin settings which i did. over phpinfo i could determine that rewrite module is present. there was one idea to add a leadding "/" before index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L] into the .htaccess file but this also didnt helped.

My phpinfo: http://pastebin.com/2p0Vay3t

Many thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless mod_rewrite module exists it can be turned off for your particular domain. I suggest to contact hosting provider. If you host on your own, add "AllowOverride All" directive to your virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

If you can login to the admin area, go to System menu and click a link that suggests to update links.